# TinyMCE table control is to big, how can i show it as menu?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Volks,

i got some TinyMCE boxes with "tablecontrols" but the contolls have 9 buttons... far to much. How can i display this as Menu?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: please describe this a bit more, an image would help too

Comment: I think a images i not needed for the ones who know tablecontrols of tinyMCE. Tablecontrols have 11 buttons in the navigation and i want to get rid of this mess. I want that the tablecontrol is displayed as menu like the font menu.

Comment: ok, got it. i am not that used to the table functions. what you want i s possible i guess, but will take some effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution via a Plugin

https://github.com/claviska/tinymce-table-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time to find you a solution for this too. This is probably the way how claviska developed his table-dropdown-plugin, but it can be used to create any dropdown with own tinymce commands.

You need to add 'my_list' to your buttonlist.
An own control (list dropdown) can be created using [an own plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) (which is not that difficult to write). There you create the list box using the following function

```
    createControl: function(n, cm) {

        switch (n) {

            case 'my_list':

                listboxIdPart = 'my_list';

                console.log('cm:', cm);

                var ctrl = cm.createListBox(listboxIdPart, {
                  title : 'My list!', //optional
                  onselect : function(v) {

                    switch (v){

                        case '0':
                            tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceTableMergeCells');
                            return;
                        }
                        case '1':
                            tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceTableSplitCells');
                            return;
                        }
                        case '2':
                            tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceTableDeleteCol');
                            return;
                        }
                        case '3':
                            tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceTableDeleteRow');
                            return;
                        }
                        // ... etc ...
                  }
                });

                // add options to the list
                // first param is the string that shows up in the list, second one is the value associated with that option
                ctrl.add('1', '1'); // '1' or whatever name you prefer
                ctrl.add('2', '2');
                ctrl.add('3', '3');
                // ... etc ...

                // Return the new listbox instance
                return ctrl;
        }
        return null;
    },
```

You will find all necessary [mceCommands for tables listed in the tinycme docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3atable) and additoionally in the tinymce developement version (not minified) under tiny_mce/plugins/table/editor_src.js line 1780 ff. This way you can influence the look and feel of your list(it should be possible to even include buttons instead of text elements in the list).